# Sqlite android crash adapter of listview when scrolling

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, crash

I have a adapter to the ListView where I charge data matches with a arraylist of matches and into the adapter

I make a select of a "Team" finding by cod_team that is cod_teamhome in the Match but get the name of the team.

The problem is when I scrolling into the ListView crash when I get the name of the team. Any idea because crash?

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }
        Match match = data.get(position);

        TextView textViewHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.teamHome);

        Team teamHome = new Team();

        /+++ CRASH IN THE NEXT LINE +++/
        teamHome = dbHelper.getTeam(match.getCod_teamhome());

        textViewHome.setText(teamHome.getNom_equipo());
```

Get name of Team in Sqlite:

```
public Team getTeam(long team_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM teams WHERE cod_team = " + team_id;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();

        Team team = new Team();
        team.setCod_team(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(cod_team)));  

        team.setName_Team(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(nameteam))));
        return team;
    }
```

Sqlite DATABASE:

> Match(cod_match, cod_teamhome, cod_teamvisitor, goals_home,
>   goals_visitor), When cod_match is primary key
>
> Team(cod_team, nameteam), When cod_team is primary key

Log:

> Could not allocate CursorWindow
>   '/data/data/app/databases/databasename' of size 2097152 due to error
>   -12.
>
> android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window
>   allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=553 (# cursors opened by
>   this proc=553)

Comment: wt if u didnt find the data in sqlite

Comment: also close the cursor as well before return statement